# How to auto connect Intermec CK scanner to wifi

Tags: barcode-scanner, windows-ce

I have a few Intermec CK3, CK7 scanners and when the connection drops it does not auto connect.
Is there any way to make a default connection? Or to force a auto connection to a specific wifi network?

Answer (score 0):

These are a/b/g devices, which work only on 2.4GHz bands, which is notoriously congested.

Details of the site aren't available, but these are most commonly used in warehouses. Those are from Wi-Fi point of view difficult deployments in the first place starting with just the materials involved. There's usually a lot of metal, which bounces the Wi-Fi signal every which way. The shelves don't stay nicely and uniformly packed due to constantly changing inventory, which changes the way Wi-Fi signal propagates through the space.

Not much can be done on the scanners themselves, basically just ensuring the OS and drivers are up-to-date. Connectivity problems in these situations are practically always fixed by adjusting the infrastructure. This can mean moving or adding APs etc.

In new sites by far the most common cause for connectivity issues is that either pre-deployment site survey was never done, or it was done before the site was taken into production, i.e. shelves were empty. When they get filled, signal propagates entirely differently than it does in empty space.

When connectivity issues appear in an existing site where the Wi-Fi performance was previously acceptable, there are usually 3 root causes.

- The site has been re-organized for efficiency or to accommodate new forklifts and other equipment. In this kind of environments there should always be a line-of-view between the scanner and an AP. If shelves are moved, the previous clear lines-of-view change or get entirely blocked. The first step towards remedy in this case is to move the APs so that lines-of-view are restored.
- Old APs have been replaced with new models. Because the newer devices have different capabilities, an upgrade like this should always be treated like a new deployment, and be accompanied by a new site survey.
- The site has been repurposed. It's been previously used for example as a textile warehouse, and now for storing steel pipes. The signal will propagate entirely differently. As above, a radical repurposement also should be treated as a new deployment.

In all cases the channel selection should be done correctly. Due to [adjacent channel overlap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#2.4_GHz_(802.11b/g/n/ax)) 2.4GHz spectrum has only 3 usable channels. In Americas (and a few other places) these are 1, 6 and 11; most of the world 1, 7 and 13; in Japan also 14 can be used so 1-6-11-14 is possible. The radios should be configured for auto channel with exclusion list allowing only the 3 channels to be used. 2.4GHz is notoriously overcrowded and prone to interference. Using auto channel with exclusion list allows an AP to switch channel if it detects interference in the current one.

2.4GHz networks can also face [sticky client](https://www.wifi-professionals.com/2018/10/sticky-clients) -problems. A common misconception is that a client would roam to a new AP when it detects a stronger signal - *not so*. The client's first and foremost task is to maintain connectivity. Once a connection has been established, it will stick to that as long as it can, and roam only when the quality of the connection drops below acceptable threshold.

The remedy to sticky client -issue is to disable low data rates, commonly  <36Mb/s. The data rate the client can communicate with drops with distance, so disabling low data rates will force the client to roam already when it can't transfer at 36Mb/s.

If the scanners are mounted on forklifts and use external antennas, the condition of those antennas and their connections should be checked. The connecting cables and the antennas themselves can easily get damaged.

- [How to configure Intermec CK3 Wi-Fi settings (manual)](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/679241/Intermec-Ck3.html?page=45#manual)
- [Intermec   70-series user manual](https://usermanual.wiki/Intermec/IntermecCk70UsersManual775624.404934549/html)

***NOTE:*** Neither of the links above lead to manufacturer resources. Intermec was acquired by Honeywell 2012, and I didn't find the relevant manuals there; only for CK3X and CK3R. I have a memory of dealing with CK7 some years back, so the 70-series manual might not be appropriate. The CK3 manual should help finding the settings also in CK7.

Honeywell's KB articles on barcode scanners are available [in this Honeywell page](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/topic/0TOA0000000Tp2rOAC/bar-code-scanners). The page also contains links to Honeywell community and support.

---

*These guidelines usually help to mitigate this kind of connectivity issues. However no two sites are exactly alike, so in practice a solution can only be site-specific. Consequently the best way to resolve connectivity issues is getting onsite help from a local Wi-Fi deployment expert.*